# Conservation of momentum & coefficient of restitution - confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I have the following setup:

> Mass $A$ is $4m$ kg and moves at 3 m/s on a smooth table. It collides directly with another mass $B$, which is $m$kg, which moves in the opposite direction to $A$ and had speed 6 m/s immediately before the collision. After the mass $A$ is said to have changed direction and move at 2 m/s.

So I want to find the coefficient of restitution.

When I applied the conservation of momentum, I found that $B$ had a speed of 14 m/s and also changed direction.

But the problem is when I calculate the coefficient of restitution I get $\frac{14 - - 2}{3 - - 6} = \frac{16}{9}$ and this is greater than 1!

I thought the coefficient of restitution was between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Since 3 speeds are given and the answer does not make sense, we can guess that the speed of B after the collision must be something other than 14 m/s. You may review your momentum equations and make sure all signs are correct.

Comment: @V.F. The momentum equation is definitely correct, so it’s not that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in units of $p_0 = m{\rm m/s}$, I get an initial state momentum:

$$ p_A + p_B = (4)(3) - (6)(1) = 12 - 6 = +6 $$

Given that $p'_A = (4)(-2) = -8$:

$$ p'_B = +14 $$.

The initial energy, in units of $p_0^2/(2m)$, is:

$$ E = \frac{p^2_A}{4} + \frac{p^2_B}{1} = 36 + 36 = 72 $$

Likewise the final state energy is:

$$ E' = \frac{p'^2_A}{4} + \frac{p'^2_B}{1} = 16 + 196 = 212$$

So the energy definitely went up.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the conditions of this problem are faulty.

If we calculate a total kinetic energy before and after the collision, using speed 14m/s for B (found for the momentum equation), we'll find that the kinetic energy after the collision (assuming for simplicity m=1), 8+98=106, is greater than the kinetic energy before the collision, 18+18=36.

This explains by e>1.

Although it is not necessarily obvious at first glance, but we have to conclude that the speed of A after the collision cannot be -2m/s.

Comment: There are plenty of means by which a collision might liberate energy, so the conditions of the problem aren't necessary problematic.

Comment: Is the conservation of momentum still valid in this case though?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Was that question directed at me?  If so, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @J.Murray Sure, but then e>1 is not an issue either.

Comment: @V.F. Yes, I agree. I don’t see anything inherently wrong here.

Comment: Possibly a pre-loaded spring attached to one of the masses was released upon contact. Momentum of the system would remain constant but the kinetic energy would increase.

Comment: @BillN That would not affect the speed of the center of mass and the associated kinetic energy, which, I believe, is the case in point.

Comment: @V.F. Agree. Just giving a scenario in which the calculated coefficient of restitution would be >1. Constant velocity of center of mass is the same as constant linear momentum.

Comment: @BillN Ok. If we agree on that, then, given the conservation of momentum applied to (centers of masses of) the two original bodies, the total KE associated with them after the collision will exceed KE before the collision without any help from other possible energy sources. Hence, the problem, as stated, does not have a solution.

Comment: @V.F. That's why I mentioned the pre-loaded spring on one of the masses. That can increase the total KE without changing the momentum.